# Why safeAreaLayoutGuide is property of UIView? Why it is not associated with UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios-autolayout

Before iOS11, there was topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide are the two instance properties of UIViewController. That are deprecated in iOS11.

In iOS11, apple introduces safeAreaLayoutGuide. As per my observation it is an instance property of UIView. What is the main reason behind this strategy?

The question arises in my mind now is: Right now I have a UIView instance that is associated with UIViewController. Now I added UIScrollView as subview to main UIView. For that I apply constraints with safeAreaLayoutGuide. See below code

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Next I have to add another UIView as subview to UIScrollView. I am doing it with respect to safeAreaLayoutGuide of UIScrollView. See below code.

```
scrollView.addSubview(vwAvatar)

        vwAvatar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        vwAvatar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        vwAvatar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        vwAvatar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vwAvatar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 3.0 / 4.0).isActive = true
```

**Now my question is whether I am doing this in right way while adding Subview to UIScrollView? Or I should go with typical approach of adding constraints with leading and trailing anchors, while adding subview to UIScrollView?**

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience whit iOS11 scrollviews and safe areas, but there is a great speech about it from Apple's WWDC. I hope it helps. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/

Comment: @danieltmbr - thanks 4 the reply.